# Firebase test lab results - missing performance data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I've just uploaded my apk to Firebase and run a "Robo" test.

Test passed, I can see screenshots, logs and video, but there is **no performance results**. It says "There is no data at this location". Also in the video tab, there are no graphs underneath.

[image: Firebase Performance]

This is how it should look like according to the Firebase docs:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/images/performance-results.png

Any ideas what could went wrong?

I've run this scenario on Pixel, API Level 26. My app is an OpenGL game.

Comment: Hi @rgolcz, the best way to get help with this issue is to join the [Firebase Community](https://firebase.community/) and post this question along with your test matrix ID in the **#test-lab** channel on Slack. Someone from the Test Lab team will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the performance tab does not load initially. With the performance tab showing, simply reload the whole page and see if it shows up. I ran into the same issue and reloading fixed it for me.